# How to close DevExpress PrintPreview on Esc key

Tags: events, devexpress, xtrareport

We are migrating our reports to DevExpress. The preview tool used the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key as default to close the print preview but using DevExpress XtraReport uses <kbd>Alt + F4</kbd>.

We want to keep the user experience so I need to somewhat handle a key event in that viewer form and if it's a <kbd>Esc</kbd> key invoke it's close event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview tool in DevExpress is called `ReportPrintTool`. You can use `ReportPrintTool.PreviewForm` property or `ReportPrintTool.PreviewRibbonForm` property to get the preview form according to which type of menu (panel or ribbon) do you want. Both of them are `Form` class descendants. Now, you can just simply use `Form.KeyPreview` property and `Form.KeyDown` event to achieve the result.
Here is example:

```cs
var report = new XtraReport();

var tool = new ReportPrintTool(report);

var form = tool.PreviewRibbonForm;
form.KeyPreview = true;
form.KeyDown += (sender, e) => { if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) form.Close(); };

report.ShowRibbonPreview();
```